login and authneticate using both Individual User Accounts and Azure AD Authentication
I implemented the code by performing both Microsoft authentication and local identity authentication...when I log in using Microsoft authentication, it's working fine..when tried to log in using local identity it's authenticated but redirected to the login page again...AddAuthentication() has an issue with that.. can anyone explain how can i manage both authentications, is that possible? Is there a suggestion to sort out this?
Startup.cs
`
using System;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Piranha;
using Piranha.AttributeBuilder;
using Piranha.ImageSharp;
using Piranha.Local;
using SendbackPortal.Data;
using SendbackPortal.Models;
using SendbackPortal.Models.Templates;
using SendbackPortal.Repositories;
using SendbackPortal.Services;
using EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Piranha.Data.EF.SQLServer;
using Piranha.Manager.Editor;
using Piranha.Manager.LocalAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using SendbackPortal.Models.AccountViewModels;

namespace SendbackPortal
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            var contentRoot = configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey);
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public string conn;

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var defaultConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var advConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ADVConnection");

            services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformation>();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnection, b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
            services.AddDbContext<SQLServerDb>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnection, b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
            services.AddDbContext<DefaultDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnection, b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
            services.AddDbContext<AdvDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(advConnection, b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging()));

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+/' ";
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();

            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o => o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddSingleton<IStorage, FileStorage>();
            services.AddSingleton<IImageProcessor, ImageSharpProcessor>();
            services.AddTransient<ISecurity, IdentitySecurity>();
            services.AddScoped<IDb, SQLServerDb>();
            services.AddScoped<IApi, Api>();

            services.AddPiranha(options =>
            {
                options.UseCms();
                options.UseManager();
                options.UseFileStorage(naming: Piranha.Local.FileStorageNaming.UniqueFolderNames);
                options.UseImageSharp();
                options.UseTinyMCE();
                options.UseEF<SQLServerDb>(db =>
                    db.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            });

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<ISendbackRepository, SendbackRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IEntraClaimInterface, IEntraClaim>();
            services.AddTransient<IUsersMappingRepository, UsersMappingRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IPhysicianMessengerRepository, PhysicianMessengerRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<ILocationExclusionRepository, LocationExclusionRepository>();

            services.AddSession();

           

            // Add Microsoft authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;

            var api = services.GetService<IApi>();
            App.Init(api);

            var pageTypeBuilder = new ContentTypeBuilder(api)
                .AddType(typeof(BlogArchive))
                .AddType(typeof(StandardPage));
            pageTypeBuilder.Build();
            var postTypeBuilder = new ContentTypeBuilder(api)
                .AddType(typeof(BlogPost));
            postTypeBuilder.Build();
            EditorConfig.FromFile("editorconfig.json");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMiddleware<PasswordMiddleware>();

            app.UsePiranha(options =>
            {
                options.UseManager();
                options.UseTinyMCE();
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areaRoute",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                endpoints.MapPiranhaManager();
            });
        }
    }
}


**
external login api
**
`
//
`[HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 
 public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
 {
     var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
     var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
     return Challenge(properties, provider);
 }

 [HttpGet]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 //[Authorize(Policy = "MicrosoftIdentityPolicy")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
 {
     // Handle the error if there's any
     if (remoteError != null)
     {
         // Log the error or handle it as needed
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
     }

     // Check if the user is already signed in
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         // If the user is already signed in, just redirect to the return URL
         return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? "~/");
     }

     // Retrieve the user information from the external authentication provider
     // This is an example using claims directly
     var email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
     {
         // Handle missing email case or other user identification details
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
     }

     // Retrieve the user from the database using UserManager
     var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

     if (user == null)
     {
         // Handle case where the user does not exist in the local database
         // Create a new user if needed
         user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
         var createResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
         if (!createResult.Succeeded)
         {
             // Handle user creation failure
             return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
         }
     }

     // Sign in the user
     await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

     // Redirect to the return URL or default route
     return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? "~/");
}`


I need to how to handle both local authentication and Microsoft authentication in a single application

